# Part number generator

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a part number generator for a large project at school. I need the ability to use the function `=RANDBETWEEN(0,999999)` to generate a portion of the part number. The problem is the updating of the `=RANDBETWEEN(0,999999)`. If I reference the cell then all of the part numbers will end up with the same random number. I need a function that will save the old random number in place but keep the ability for the `=RANDBETWEEN(0,999999)` to update to generate a new number for the next part. I have been searching for 2 days for a way to do this. Hope someone can help. I have no experience with VBA and would like to keep this as a function so that it can be used by all users of the team.

Comment: You will need to use vba.  Formulas are live and any formula that references a cell will link to that cell always.  VBA will allow you to use that cell and create a value that is not linked to the changing cell.

Comment: [RANDBETWEEN](https://exceljet.net/functions/randbetween-function) is said to recalculate each time that a worksheet is opened or changed.

Comment: Maybe it's time you learned VBA/Office Script, in your case it could be as easy as one line of code...

Comment: Formulas that are dynamic cannot fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer.**

Note that RAND(), RANDBETWEEN() and all similar functions will generate new number for each RECALCULATION of a worksheet.

F9 or SHIFT+CTRL+F9 (in LibreOffice) launches a recalculation, which will make the problem visible for you.

Neither will there be any guarantee that the generated numbers are unique.

---

*Below is a function that MIGHT be a starting point for a manually or keyboard-started macro to set a certain cell to a six-digit random number with leading zeroes.*

*UNTESTED (No Excel available, is likely have at least one or two errors)*

```
function rndNum(cell)
  rndNum=WorksheetFunction.RANDBETWEEN(0,999999)
  if cell<>"" then
    Range(cell).Value="'" & WorksheetFunction.TEXT(rndNum,"000000")
  end if
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named function, say `EVAL` in the named manager:

```
=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE(x))
```

Now you can invoke this in your worksheet through:

```
=EVAL("RANDBETWEEN(0,999999)")
```

This will create a random number that will only change when you re-apply that formula in that exact cell.

Note that this will trigger your workbook to be xlsm upon saving, or else you will loose the named function (the random numbers will stay in place).

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you tell me why the file format change is important? I'm not familiar with the uses of the file types, I only know there are different types.

Comment: @Charlie Stabler .xlsm file format allows the file to contain programming (VBA code). Application security settings control how these files are opened to avoid malicious code from executing. Each user has their own security settings, though Microsoft sets a highly restrictive default.